# Erase-Increment idiom failing with 'vector iterator not compatible'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator, stdvector

I've implemented part of a SubDivide method of a position-based Quadtree like so:

```
//Give elements of mine to children, may or may not accept them.
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; ++i) {
    std::vector<T>::iterator b = _elements.begin();
    std::vector<T>::iterator e = _elements.end();
    for(std::vector<T>::iterator _iter = b; _iter != e; ++_iter) {
        if(_children[i]->Add(*_iter)) continue;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when the tree subdivides the parent does not remove the element from its own container if a child node accepts it, so I changed it to use the erase-increment idiom:

```
//Give elements of mine to children, may or may not accept them.
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; ++i) {
    std::vector<T>::iterator b = _elements.begin();
    for(std::vector<T>::iterator _iter = b; _iter != _elements.end(); /** DO NOTHING **/) {
        if(_children[i]->Add(*_iter) == false) {
            ++_iter;
            continue;
        }
        _elements.erase(_iter++);
    }
}
```

But this is failing with `vector iterator not compatible` on the conditional check of the for loop after the child accepts the element and the parent erases the copy out of its container. I suspect the iterators past the erased iterator are being invalidated (as they should) but I have this exact code elsewhere (the conditional inside the for loop is different but otherwise the code involving the iterators is the same) and it does not fail.

Comment: `vector`'s `erase()` "invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase", including your incremented iterator. You can just use the return value of `erase()` anyway: `_iter = _elements.erase(_iter);`.

Comment: @T.C. Not with visual studio 2010

Comment: Just tested and it works on my VS 2010.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry about that. I was thinking `std::erase` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard has this to say about `std::vector`'s `erase()` (§23.3.6.5 [vector.modifiers]/p3):

> ```
> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of
>   the erase.

Thus, erase-increment simply does not work with `vector`s. The `erase()` call invalidates the incremented iterator. Use `_iter = _elements.erase(_iter);` instead.

Testing code - this compiles and runs fine on my VS 2010:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(40);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(60);

    std::vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator _iter = b; _iter != v.end(); /** DO NOTHING **/) {
        if(*_iter != 10) {
            ++_iter;
            continue;
        }
        _iter=v.erase(_iter); // v.erase(iter++) causes abort()
    }
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```